# Python string format: When to use !s conversion flag

Tags: python, string, string-formatting

What's the difference between these 2 string format statements in Python:

```
'{0}'.format(a)
'{0!s}'.format(a)
```

Both have the same output if `a` is an integer, list or dictionary. Is the first one `{0}` doing an implicit `str()` call?

[Source](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#format-string-syntax)

PS: keywords: exclamation / bang "!s" formatting

Answer (score 37, accepted):

It is mentioned in the documentation:

> The conversion field causes a type coercion before formatting.
>   Normally, the job of formatting a value is done by the `__format__()`
>   method of the value itself. However, in some cases it is desirable to
>   force a type to be formatted as a string, overriding its own
>   definition of formatting. By converting the value to a string before
>   calling `__format__()`, the normal formatting logic is bypassed.
>
> Two conversion flags are currently supported: '`!s`' which calls
>   `str()` on the value, and '`!r`' which calls `repr()`.

An example can be taken (again from [the documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#formatexamples)) to show the difference:

```
>>> "repr() shows quotes: {!r}; str() doesn't: {!s}".format('test1', 'test2')
"repr() shows quotes: 'test1'; str() doesn't: test2"
```

Comment: I get the same result whether I use `{0}` or `{0!s}` with a string argument to format. How does `repr()` come into picture?

Comment: @click `{x}` and `{x!s}` will give the same result for strings and integers. Type coercion occurs if you've a different `__format__()` and `__str__()` defined (eg. for some custom class, like a vector or complex number etc.).

Comment: You'll almost always get the same result for `{}` and `{!s}`, because of [this suggestion from the Python docs](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/string.html#format-specification-mini-language): `A general convention is that an empty format string ("") produces the same result as if you had called str() on the value.` All the built-in types I'm aware of follow this convention.

Answer (score 28):

Simply said:

- `'{0}'.format(a)` will use the result of `a.__format__()` to display the value
- `'{0!s}'.format(a)` will use the result of `a.__str__()` to display the value
- `'{0!r}'.format(a)` will use the result of `a.__repr__()` to display the value

---

```
>>> class C:
...     def __str__(self): return "str"
...     def __repr__(self): return "repr"
...     def __format__(self, format_spec): return "format as " + str(type(format_spec))
... 
>>> c = C()
>>> print "{0}".format(c)
format as <type 'str'>
>>> print u"{0}".format(c)
format as <type 'unicode'>
>>> print "{0!s}".format(c)
str
>>> print "{0!r}".format(c)
repr
```

Concerning the second argument of `__format__`, to quote [PEP 3101](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3101/) *"Controlling Formatting on a Per-Type Basis"*:

> The 'format_spec' argument will be either
>   a string object or a unicode object, depending on the type of the
>   original format string.  The `__format__` method should test the type
>   of the specifiers parameter to determine whether to return a string or
>   unicode object.  It is the responsibility of the `__format__` method
>   to return an object of the proper type.

Answer (score 2):

Thanks to the comment & answer from @hjpotter92 for explanation:

Here's an example that shows the difference (it's when you override the `__format__` method)

```
class MyClass:
    i = 12345
    def __format__(self, i):
        return 'I Override'

>>> obj = MyClass()

>>> '{0}'.format(obj)
'I Override'

>>> '{0!s}'.format(obj)
'<__main__.MyClass instance at 0x021AA6C0>'
```